# Why are some Java functions able to change an immutable Kotlin object?

Tags: java, kotlin, collections, interop

I was surprised to see that this program even compiles, but the result surprised me even more:

```
import java.util.Collections.swap

fun main(args: Array<String>) 
{
    val immutableList = List(2) { it } // contents are [0, 1] 
    swap(immutableList, 0, 1)
    println(immutableList) // prints [1, 0]
}
```

The `swap` function is implemented in the library as:

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
        list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
    }
```

where the `List` is a mutable Java list, not an immutable Kotlin one. So I thought that other Java functions will work as well. For instance:

```
reverse(immutableList)
```

works, but others, such as the `fill` function, does not even compile:

```
fill(immutableList, 3)
```

produces the following error message:

> Type inference failed: fun  fill(p0: MutableList!,
>   p1: T!): Unit cannot be applied to (List,Int) Type mismatch:
>   inferred type is List but MutableList! was expected

The `List` argument of the `fill` function however has different type bounds than `reverse`:

```
public static <T> void fill(List<? super T> list, T obj)

public static void reverse(List<?> list)
```

so it seems that without the type bounds, the Java functions can do whatever they want.

Can someone explain how is this possible? Is this by design, or is it just a limitation of the interop?

Comment: I don't have your full code so I don't know, but base on the error message I can say that on kotlin MutableList is an interface and it extended from the interface List. 

So, 
- a MutableList is also a List
- a List may not be a MutableList

Comment: Wild guess that `reverse()` and `swap()` don't change the overall content of the list. They only change the order. `fill()` would change the content of the list

Comment: Why are you getting a Kotlin compiler error for a Java method?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I am sorry, but my knowledge of the interop is so bad, that I do not even know if that is supposed to happen or not.

Comment: Oh, do you mean calling that method from Kotlin doesn't compile?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, I will update to clarify.

Comment: The question is how does Kotlin decide whether a Java method takes a `List` or `MutableList` parameter. I searched for it and only found lots of talks about nullability, but nothing about the decision for `List` or `MutableList`.

Comment: It's because of Kotlin heuristic. It is common practice to use constructions such as `List<? super T>` to add something generic to list. Kotlin changed this construction to `List<in T>`. But you always can just cast Immutable list to Mutable one and it will compile. For example this code `Hm.fill(listOf(1) as MutableList<Int>, 2)` will compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**functions that doesn't compile has nothing to do with kotlin but how covariant and contravariant collections are handled by java.**

from [Java Generics and Collections](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do)

> You cannot put anything into a type declared with an extends
>   wildcard—except for the value null, which belongs to every reference
>   type

for example if you have following code.

```
List<? extends Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then you can do this

```
 numbers.add(null);
```

but if you tried to do any of the following

```
numbers.set(0, Integer.valueOf(10)); // case 1
numbers.set(1, numbers.get(0)); // case 2
```

in **case 1** compiler will not let you do it because there is no way for the compiler to know the exact type of list, in this case its a list of integers in some other case it may be assigned a list of doubles based on some runtime condition.

in **case 2** the compiler is not able to confirm the type of object that is being inserted into the list, and an error is produced. you can solve the problem in case 2 using [Wildcard Capture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html).

**Second is your question about mutating kotlin lists in java methods.**

we have to understand that kotlin collections classes are same old java collection classes and kotlin doesn't have its own collections implementation. what kotlin does is that it divides the java collection interfaces into mutable and read only.
if you create an array list in kotlin and then check its class you will get same java.util.ArrayList

Now given that java doesn't have any notion of mutable list and read only list as kotlin does, there is no way to stop java methods from mutating your read only kotlin list. because for java code that is just a list implementation.

**following is the relevant text from book** [Kotlin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action)

> When you need to call a Java method and pass a collection as an
>   argument, you can do so directly without any extra steps. For example,
>   if you have a Java method that takes a java.util.Collection as a
>   parameter, you can pass any Collection or Mutable Collection value as
>   an argument to that parameter.
>
> This has important consequences with  regard to mutability of
>   collections. Because Java doesn’t distinguish between read-only and
>   mutable collections, Java code can modify the collection even if it’s
>   declared as a read-only Collection on the Kotlin side. The Kotlin
>   compiler can’t fully analyze what’s being done to the collection in
>   the Java code, and **therefore there’s no way for Kotlin to reject a
>   call passing a read-only Collection to Java code that modifies it**.

Comment: “*then compiler will not let you put anything into that variable*”—well except for `null` or for a value taken from the same list, as `swap`, `sort`, `reverse` or `rotate` do. And as you said, even when adding didn’t work, removing still did.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that your version of `swap` is not compileable. It is the result of decompiling the actual library code that casts the List to a raw type so it can read and write with it despite the wildcard.

The `swap` method uses a wildcard type, and so there is no limitation between the interface mapping in the interop. Kotlin maps both List and MutableList to Java's List, so it unfortunately allows misuse like this. I suppose it is necessary to avoid preventing use of Java libraries.

Your `fill` method uses a contravariant (consumer) bounded type `<? super T>` which is incompatible with Kotlin's List. Kotlin's List is declared with a covariant (producer) type only: `List<out T>`. So they are not a match for each other.